# What does it mean for a binary to "run as root" and how can I determine it for processes?

Tags: linux, permissions, process, users, terminology

I've heard that vulnerabilities specifically in Linux programs (binaries in this case) that "are running as root" are dangerous because for example, if some network/web server is "running as root" as there is a vulnerability found in e.g. the front-line packet parser, this could allow an attacker to compromise the machine more severely than a program that is not "running as root."

I am familiar with `setuid` binaries, in which the `setuid` bit is set, which means that even when the binary is run by user A, it is run under the context of a different user. But I guess my confusion lies in the phrasing - how does a program "run as root?" Is the `process` itself taking on the root user identity on the machine? Why specifically is a `process` that runs as root more dangerous and how can I tell exactly which processes are running as root on my linux system? I see that for example some executables are *owned* by the `root` user or group, but does this mean that inherently, they are always "running as root" when they are loaded into memory by the program loaders?

Answer (score 2):

Programs do not "*run as root*" !
root (in this context) is a user when a program is… a program.

- The root **user** runs programs as (the) root (user).
- Non-root **users** run programs as (if they were the) root (user).

In such a situation the user (whatever its *real id*) is considered having the same privileges than the root user.
Therefore the program will be capable of killing / change the priority of processes owned by root, access to files/directories/device nodes with respect to root's access rights and take benefits of more advantageous security limits.

This can be the case if :

- the program is an executable file owned by root with its *set user ID on execution* set,
- if some user launched the program using `sudo`,
- if, of course, the root user launched the program.

The first column of a `ps -ef` will tell you the *effective* owner of all the processes running on your system. If you can read *root* then, this process is run on behalf of a user having root privileges.

This is potentially dangerous because of the capabilities listed hereabove. If the program is buggy or if whatever sort of procedure managed to exploit some of its vulnerabilities, it might well make an inappropriate use of root's power.

Also note that a program launched with root's privileges can drop them if using the [`setuid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html) system call and eventually regain these privileges at some point using the [`seteuid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seteuid.2.html) system call.
Therefore the process' owner is not necessarily fixed for the all life of the process.

Answer (score 0):

When people say "are running as root" they mean any or all of these situations:

- A program with setuid bit assigned, ran from User A.
- A program that is set to run as a daemon by the operating system.
- A program running as root via a kernel root kit hidden from detection.

The likely most common scenario is the daemon, using exploitable code. Such as vulnerabilities in OpenSSH daemon or other servers like Apache.